# How can I cancel DownloadOperation?

Tags: uwp, download, background-transfer

For downloading I use BackgroundDownloader. If user needs to delete a file(status = downloading), I need to cancel DownloadOperation.
But I did not find method in the DownloadOperation`s list. Tell me, please, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I cancel DownloadOperation?

You could cancel download easily with cancel token. You could pass `CancellationToken` to  `DownloadOperation`  when you start `DownloadOperation`

```
await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
```

If you want to cancel above  `DownloadOperation`, you just call the following.

```
cts.Cancel();
cts.Dispose();
```

For more detail please refer [`BackgroundTransfer`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer) code sample.